# Looking for a USB camera with small field of view / high zoom

Tags: ros, usb, usb-camera, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a camera for computer vision that has a FOV of about 11°.
To facilitate the design, it would be great if it could connect directly via USB to a computer running ROS.

However all the webcams I'm looking at have a FOV of 70°-120° and all the more advanced cameras either only have analog live output or firewire. I would like to avoid Firewire, since almost no small PC still suppports it.

Does anybody know of a usb camera with a small fov, exchangeable optics or hardware zoom?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37900/looking-for-a-usb-camera-with-small-field-of-view-/-high-zoom/) by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you may have good luck with the [Point Grey Firefly MV](http://www.ptgrey.com/products/fireflymv/fireflymv_usb_firewire_cmos_camera.asp).  It's a fairly high quality camera, and it has exchangeable optics, using the CS or C mount for cameras.

I think that the CS mount lenses should be available from many places, as it is frequently used with security cameras.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-04**:
You could also look at the Point Grey Chameleon USB 2.0 cameras: http://www.ptgrey.com/products/chameleon/chameleon_usb_camera.asp . Note that those Point Grey USB cameras have good ROS camera driver support using the camera1394 driver, as they expose IIDC (firewire) camera interfaces over USB.

**Comment by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) on 2012-07-05**:
Those look great! Manual focus might be a bit annoying, but as long as we are flying at a set altitude, and considering the small sensor this should be easy to preset.